# Error Defining Explode in Pie Chart (Donut Chart) using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pie-chart

I have a dataframe that will be visualized. This is the code to obtain that dataframe:

`zonasi = (df.groupby('kodya / kab')['customer'].nunique()) zonasi`

this is the output from the code above:

```
kab bandung                  1
kab bandung barat            4
kab banyumas                 2
kab batang                   1
kab bekasi                  29
kab bogor                   13
kab kudus                   11
kab tangerang               15
kab tegal                    2
kota adm jakarta barat      14
kota adm jakarta pusat       6
kota adm jakarta selatan    10
kota adm jakarta timur      23
kota adm jakarta utara       9
kota balikpapan              1
kota bandung                12
kota bekasi                 12
kota semarang               11
kota surabaya                3
kota surakarta               2
kota tangerang              10
kota tasikmalaya             2
no data                     44
```

I want to visualize the output into pie chart, but since the x labels ('kodya / kab') have a lot of different unique values, the xlabels are overlapping. So, I want to try using `explode` to visualize the pie chart (donut chart).

I tried using this code:

```
`#colors
colors = sns.color_palette('husl')

#explosion
explode = (0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05)

plt.pie(zonasi, colors = colors, autopct='%.2f%%', startangle = 90, pctdistance = 0.85, explode = explode)

#draw circle
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.70,fc = 'white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)

#Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle
ax.axis('equal')  
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()`
```

but it returns this error:

`'explode' must be of length 'x'`

The thing is, I want to use the visualization code to different dataframe, so the xlabels will be different from one another. How can I define the explode variable so it can adjust to the xlabels automatically?

This is the example of what my output will look like:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: You could try `plt.pie(..., explode=[0.05]*len(zonasi))`. And maybe also `colors = sns.color_palette('husl', len(zonasi))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

data = {'kodya / kab': ['kab bandung', 'kab bandung barat', 'kab banyumas', 'kab batang', 'kab bekasi', 'kab bogor', 'kab kudus', 'kab tangerang', 'kab tegal', 'kota adm jakarta barat', 'kota adm jakarta pusat', 'kota adm jakarta selatan', 'kota adm jakarta timur', 'kota adm jakarta utara', 'kota balikpapan', 'kota bandung', 'kota bekasi', 'kota semarang', 'kota surabaya', 'kota surakarta', 'kota tangerang', 'kota tasikmalaya', 'no data'],
        'customer': [1, 4, 2, 1, 29, 13, 11, 15, 2, 14, 6, 10, 23, 9, 1, 12, 12, 11, 3, 2, 10, 2, 44]}

zonasi = pd.DataFrame(data)
zonasi.set_index('kodya / kab', inplace=True)  # set the index to 'kodya / kab'

colors = sns.color_palette('husl')

explode = np.zeros(len(zonasi))
explode[1:5] = 0.1 

zonasi.plot.pie(y='customer', colors=colors, autopct='%.2f%%', startangle=90, pctdistance=0.85, explode=explode,legend=False)
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 0.70, fc='white')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]